# Rabl / Will Paginate setting name of root child

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-3, api, will-paginate, rabl

I wonder if anyone can help. I'm trying to migrate our old Rails Model#to_json for our API to make versioning easier in the longer term. I'm struggling at the first hurdle because of Rabl and Will Paginate.

We currently override WillPaginate::Collection#as_json

```
module WillPaginate
  class Collection

    alias :as_json_without_paginate :as_json   

    def as_json(options = {})

      # RABL seemingly passing JSON::Ext::Generator::State into as_json
      unless options.is_a?(Hash)
        options = {}
      end

      json = {
        :page => current_page
        :per_page => per_page,
        :total_entries => total_entries,
        :entries => as_json_without_paginate(options)
      }
    end

  end
end
```

So @collection.to_json would return something like

```
{
  "total_entries": 1,
  "page": 1,
  "entries": [
    {
      "follow": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "TEST"
      }
    }
  ],
  "per_page": 10
}
```

However when I try to do the following in RABL

```
node(:page) {|m| @follows.current_page }
node(:per_page) {|m| @follows.per_page }
node(:total_entries) {|m| @follows.total_entries}

child(@follows => :entries) do
  # extends 'follows/show'
  attributes :id, :name
end
```

The name of the child is automatically set to 'entry', I want to set it to 'follow' to be consistent with our current API but having no luck whatsoever.

```
{
  "total_entries": 1,
  "page": 1,
  "entries": [
    {
      "entry": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "TEST"
      }
    }
  ],
  "per_page": 10
}
```

Can anyone give me any pointers. I've been trying to trace back through the source and it just seems that the name of the root object name for the child is always implied.

Answer (score 3):

I've encountered the same exact bug, the problem seems to be setting the object_root to false. Here is the same solution I proposed in response to another stackoverflow question:
[wrong child root name in rabl and can't set child root name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18264416/wrong-child-root-name-in-rabl-and-cant-set-child-root-name)

```
child( {@follow => :entries}, {:object_root => false} ) do
   # extends 'follows/show'
   attributes :id, :name
end
```

**Note both the round parentheses "()" and braces "{}".**

Hope this helps. It worked perfectly in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `:object_root => false` to your `child` block should do it.

```
child(@follows => :entries, :object_root => false) do
  # extends 'follows/show'
  attributes :id, :name
end
```